# Intent for contacts with phone number

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, android-contacts

Please, is it possible to pick from contacts only with phone number/s using intent and default contacts app?

Maybe some modification of this (shows selection from all contacts):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_ID);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can open a cursor on the contacts and run through getting the contacts with phone numbers. You could recreate the contact picker activity that is shown from the intent you mentioned using this cursor (throwing them into a listview to pick from)

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor phoneCur = cr.query( 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                null,
                null, 
                null, 
                null); 
        while (phoneCur.moveToNext()) { 
            String phone = phoneCur.getString(
                      phoneCur.getColumnIndex(
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
            //do something, check if empty...
        } 
        phoneCur.close();
```

with this approach you will also need the read contact permission in you manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: Not exactly a solution I was hoping for. But I guess there is no other way, is there? So I am accepting this answer, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of another way, but I'll update it if I find one.